# Ctrl C won't kill looped subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, system-calls, kill

Is there a proper way to create a script that loops through files in a folder and executes a subprocess that can be externally killed with Ctrl C? I have something like the following embedded in a pipeline and cannot Ctrl C it from the command line when the main process is killed.

Example script:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys

input_directory = sys.argv[1]

for file in os.listdir(os.path.abspath(input_directory)):
    output = file + "_out.out"
    command = ['somescript.py', file, output]
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(command)
    except:
        print "Command Failed"
```

I would then execute program:

```
Example_script.py /path/to/some/directory/containing/files/
```

While it is looping, if I see the command failed, I want use Ctrl C. However, it fails and continues to run additional subprocesses despite the main script has been destroyer with Ctrl C. Is there a proper way to write something like this that can kill the childs (additional subprocess) with Ctrl C?

Any help, or pointing me in the direction is appreciated greatly. I am currently looking for a good method to do.

Comment: Why not just exit your program when you catch the exception, after printing "Command Failed"? - You can get more complicated than this by adding signal handling to your code that gets called when a child dies, but in this case, it seems like you just want to stop looping when you get a failure. ... or are you saying that you don't get an exception in this case?

Comment: @Steve I don't know why I haven't tried that yet. lol That literally hasn't hit me yet. Thanks! If I wanted to try more complicated signal handling how would I go about this? Would I check the status of the subprocess when it returns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have in your try/except block is too permissive, such that when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is also handled by that same exception handler as the one that `print "Command Failed"`, and as that is now properly handled there, the flow of the program is continued through the for loop.  What you should do is:

1. Replace `except:` with `except Exception:` so that the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception will not be trapped, such that any time <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed the program will terminate (including subprocesses that isn't stuck in some non-terminatable state);
2. After the `print` statement, `break` out of the loop to prevent further execution from happening, if that is the intended behavior that you want this program to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try this as well. :) I will be sure to respond with an update.

Answer (score 0):

I think  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Z</kbd>  can also help you to push the execution to background and suspended.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, that way you can deal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in whatever manner you want.

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys

input_directory = sys.argv[1]

for file in os.listdir(os.path.abspath(input_directory)):
    output = file + "_out.out"
    command = ['somescript.py', file, output]
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(command)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print "Interrupted"
        sys.exit(1)
    except:
        print "Command Failed"
```

However I agree with the other posters in that your exception is too vague, and you should be more specific in what can and can't fail.